# Me marca error el importar la dependencia de com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Al tratar de importar la dependencia de de com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics me sale el siguiente error "Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
Affected Modules: app" y mi gradle esta bien hasta que importo la dependencia me sale el error ya especifiado. Mi gradle es el siguiente

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.rentaaapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.rentaaapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.2")
    implementation ("com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0")
}
```

Al agregar la depedendencia de firebase-analytics y darle en "Sync now" me sale un warning y la dependencia es muy necesaria para mi app asi que no la puedo eliminar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Si usas la BoM de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more?hl=es-419#bom), no tienes que poner la versión de las bibliotecas que quieres añadir. Puede que el problema venga porque estás poniendo una versión a esta dependencia: `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0`, prueba a ponerla así: **`com.google.firebase:firebase-auth`** Y, pon todas las dependencias debajo de la BoM por si acaso.